# Is there any iOS open source web browser

Tags: ios, safari, browser, bookmarks

I am creating web browser, have you any one knowing any open source web browser like safari, which content Add Bookmark, multipage etc functionality.

Comment: Take a look at Firefox iOS. https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios Though it might be more complicated than what you are asking for.

Answer (score 6):

There are **many**. For example:

- [TSMiniWebBrowser](https://github.com/tonisalae/TSMiniWebBrowser) - In-App web browser control for iOS apps
- [iOS-OnionBrowser](https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-OnionBrowser) - An open-source, privacy-enhancing web browser for iOS, utilizing the Tor anonymity network
- [DZNWebViewController](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNWebViewController) - A simple iPhone/iPad web browser.
- [PBWebViewController](https://github.com/kmikael/PBWebViewController) - A light-weight, simple and customizable web browser component for iOS.

Comment: Any of these has multiple tabs feature?

Comment: @LittleTinyDev I think Firefox and Brave have that feature.